# Should the script component be called when 0 rows are sent to it in a data flow?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I ran into a very odd situation with an SSIS package I have been working with.

I have a foreach loop that contains a data flow task which executes for every record in a recordset object populated prior to the loop.

In the dataflow task I have an ADO.NET source, a lookup, and finally a destination script component. The script component initializes a datatable in *PreExecute*, adds each row from the input, and post sends the datatable as a table valued parameter to a stored procedure. The lookup task is set up to only send non-matching rows to the script component.

The odd situation is that I found when all rows on the lookup were matched the script component was still being executed with 0 rows sent to it. This resulted in an error in the stored proc as I was only ever expecting it to be called when the script component received more than 0 rows. I have corrected the issue in the stored proc itself by first doing a check that there is actually data passed in.

In other packages I have very similar situations with destination script components set up after lookups where 0 records get passed in, and have not seen this behavior occur there - the only difference is that they're not within foreach loops.

So, I'd really like to know, for future reference, if it is the expected behavior of an an SSIS script component that it would execute with 0 rows passed in?

Comment: @Siva Yes, it is a destination script component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`PreExecute`** and **`PostExecute`** methods will execute even if there are **no rows** to redirect from the following *`Lookup Transformation`* outputs to the *`Script Component`* configured as *`Destination`* component within *Data Flow Task*.

- *Lookup Match Output*
- *Lookup No Match Output*

Make sure that the package that you believe is working differently than the one not working is configured in the same manner.

Comment: Interesting - after thinking further about the package/proc where the problem does not occur, there is a similar loop occurring but it's in the stored proc itself. So, if there were a blank table valued parameter passed in it would simply not execute any of the logic within the loop. Thanks for the quick answer, Siva!